# SWD programming adapter

Tags: embedded, jtag, swd

Are [ARM-JTAG-20-10](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/ARM-JTAG-20-10/1188-1016-ND/3471401?WT.mc_id=IQ_7595_G_pla3471401&wt.srch=1&wt.medium=cpc&WT.srch=1&gclid=Cj0KEQjwgJq-BRCFqcLW8_DU9agBEiQAz8Koh0qQ1c82ucgBrJi4TsSh5_U0BVRleaF3YNFOwFqfcY8aAkeN8P8HAQ) and [J-LINK 9-PIN CORTEX-M ADAPTER](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/segger-microcontroller-systems/8.06.02-J-LINK-9-PIN-CORTEX-M-ADAPTER/899-1012-ND/2421158) pin compatible? Why such a big price difference?

Comment: should be, did you check the documentation, they are in theory just converting from the new smaller cortex-m/swd foot print to the older arm jtag footprint.  you should check the schematics for the two and see what you think

Comment: Looks compatible per the schematics, but why such a big price difference ($36 vs $6)?

Comment: Olimex vs Segger, everything Segger is way over priced.

Comment: Some of the Olimex stuff might be on shaky legal ground in some jurisdictions in the cases where they rely on the OEM software interface. This isn't one of those cases, though, and this is good to know, because I have a bunch of J-Links and we're moving to the smaller Cortex-M connector.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is about prices for hardware-tools, not software.

Comment: The question is about the difference between two seemingly compatible hardware tools that allow software to be uploaded into an MCU.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the price levels and policies of two different manufacturers ("Why is a fiat cheaper than a porsche if both allow you to cruise at the same max speed of your home country?"), the quality of the electronic hardware may differ notably, which can impact the maximum baudrate you can run with a given target PCB.

Furthermore, some JTAG pinout adapters include additional features like galvanic isolation (I haven't checked whether this applies to the Segger piece you mention.).